# Foreign key constraint triggered even though data does exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables `INTRFCTRL` and `INTERROR`, both with IDENTITY columns `FILEID`

INTERROR has the following foreign key attached

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[INTERROR]  WITH CHECK 
ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_INTERROR_0] FOREIGN KEY([FILEID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[INTRFCTRL] ([FILEID])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[INTERROR] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_INTERROR_0]
```

I am inserting data from a temp table into `INTRFCTRL` and then attempting to do the same into `INTERROR` and controlling the identity column value using DBCC RESEED

I run this successfully and can see that the FILEID value of 67001 is present in the INTRFCTRL table

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT (INTRFCTRL, RESEED, 67000)
INSERT INTO dbo.INTRFCTRL SELECT FILEHASH,CASENO,INTNO,FILENAM,... 
FROM INTRFCTRL_TEMP
```

When I then try to run

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT (INTERROR, RESEED, 67000)
INSERT INTO dbo.INTERROR SELECT INTRFLINENO,CASENO... FROM INTERROR_TEMP
```

I get

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_INTERROR_0". The conflict occurred in database "ESSDEV", table
>   "dbo.INTRFCTRL", column 'FILEID'.

Yet I can see the data in INTRFCTRL

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Probably INTRFCTRL_TEMP and INTERROR_TEMP have a different number of rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to use `OUTPUT` clause instead of manipulating `IDENTITY` value:

> I am inserting data from a temp table into INTRFCTRL and then attempting to do the same into INTERROR

```
DECLARE @MyTableVar table(identity_col INT, file_id INT );

INSERT INTO dbo.INTRFCTRL(col_list, ...)
OUTPUT inserted.identity_col, inserted.file_id  --get inserted identity value
INTO @MyTabVar
SELECT FILEHASH,CASENO,INTNO,FILENAM,... 
FROM INTRFCTRL_TEMP;

SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.INTERROR ON;

INSERT INTO dbo.INTERROR(col_list, ...)
SELECT t.identity_col, INTRFLINENO,CASENO... 
FROM INTERROR_TEMP it
JOIN @MyTabVar t
  ON it.fileId = t.File_id;

SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.INTERROR OFF;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting IDENTITY_INSERT OFF on INTERROR and take the FILEID values from INTRFCTRL table.